# How to group tuples in a list with multiple values matching

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, grouping

I want to group a list of tuples with multiple common values as efficiently as possible. I know the long method of doing it but wondering what a quicker more "Pythonic" way of doing it would be.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
lst = [('a', '1', 1),
       ('a', '1', 2),
       ('a', '2', 2),
       ('b', '1', 1),
       ('c', '1', 1)]

result = [
        [('a', '1', 1), ('a', '1', 2)],
        [('a', '2', 1)],
        [('b', '1', 1)]
        [('c', '1', 1)]
    ]
```

ideally the true result I'd like to get to would be:

```
result = [
        [('a', '1', 1), ('a', '1', 2)],
    ]
```

where if there is no matching pairs then it excludes them but I think I can do that with `set()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
r = {}
for i in lst:
    r.setdefault((i[0], i[1]), []).append(i)   #key -> First 2 values

print(list(r.values()))
#OR print([i for i in r.values() if len(i) > 1])
```

**Output:**

```
[[('a', '1', 1), ('a', '1', 2)],
 [('a', '2', 2)],
 [('b', '1', 1)],
 [('c', '1', 1)]]
```

Comment: It's almost what I'm looking for, issue is it's grouping them by the first value in the tuple and not the first two. Let me edit my question quickly to be a bit more clear. My bad, but I love this as a solution if grouping by one value was it :)

Comment: If you need the first two the use `r.setdefault((i[0], i[1]), []).append(i)` or `r.setdefault(tuple(i[:2]), []).append(i)`

Comment: This is exactly it. I didn't know it would work like that :) do you mind if you can modify your answer with this so I can mark it as the correct one?